# Awk error argument list too long, only two variables

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to sum two numbers of a table (in file) with awk (inside a loop), using variables passed from a bash script like described below. The numbers that I am dealing with ($value) are floating point values. $value only contains one number. Note that the line where the error occurs is 126, 125 is working fine.

```
111 while read line
112 do
120             n=2
121             sum=0
122 
123             for x in $(seq 1 $number)
124             do
125                     value=$(echo "$line" | awk -v n="$n" '{print $n}')    # I am just getting the values to sum up here
126                     sum=$(awk -v sum="$sum" -v value="$value" '{sum = sum + value; print sum}')
                        n=$((n+1))
129             done
     done < $file
```

Where $number is defined previously.

I get the following error:

```
./script.sh: line 126: /bin/awk: Argument list too long
```

I am only trying to pass two variables on the awk command on this line, any idea why I am getting this error?

An example of the table in the "file":

```
  A       -0.717616       -0.623398       -0.214494       -0.352871
  B       -0.19373        -0.140626       -0.0523623      0.0248858
  C       -0.0822092      -0.302354       0.347158        -0.0373262
  D       0.310213        0.312805        0.114366        0.353496
  E       -0.175354       -0.0263985      -0.125694       -0.155082
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a tough time understanding what you are trying to do, but reading a file line by line in a loop, then moving through fields in that line one by one, then adding the results, both in awk, seem like a really bizarre way to solve whatever it is that you are trying to solve. I'm betting here that this whole thing can be done with a single awk command. Can you share an example of your file, and then what your expected results are?

Comment: One problem is that `print` is outputting the entire input line, not just the value of `sum`.

Comment: The thing is that I am using that script on different files that have different numbers of fields per line. The number of field per line is basically contained in $number. I added a sample of what a file could look like, this one has 4 columns, but as I just mentioned, this number could be different. The expected results would be the sum of all fields, for each line. I hope that makes more sense! Let me know if there is anything else I can specify.

Comment: Also, since you haven't specified an *input file* for that line, it is reading from the input file it inherits from the enclosing loops, which is your `$file`. As a result, `sum` is a very long string; the next time you try to call `awk`, the command line is, indeed, very long.

Comment: @chepner You are right I, edited my post

Comment: I tried using this line instead of line 126 previously: sum=$(echo "scale=10; $sum + $value" | bc), but I was getting syntax errors, although the calculations seemed to work and the sum results looked fine. I am basically trying to use awk to get rid of these syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your call to `awk`: you haven't specified an input file, so it is reading from its inherited standard input (which is the file the `while` loop is also trying to read from), and it outputs each line it reads, not just the value of `sum` (fixed while I was typing this).

This is a very inefficient way to add up the numbers in the file, by the way, but here is a corrected version:

```
while read line
do
    n=2
    sum=0

    for x in $(seq 1 $number)
    do
        value=$(echo "$line" | awk -v n="$n" '{print $n}')
        sum=$(awk -v sum="$sum" -v value="$value" 'BEGIN {sum = sum + value; print sum}' </dev/null)
        n=$((n+1))
    done
done < $file
```

A better solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum=0}
     {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { sum = sum + $i }}
     END {print sum}' < $file
```

Comment: It works, thank you!! I know it seems like a weird way to go about this, I tried to explain why I did it like this in a comment on my post. In any case, what you wrote works great.